# Creating a Login System like Battle.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a login system like http://us.battle.net/en/. The page is fully functional, then when you click on the "Log In" link, the page becomes dark and you can no longer interact with any of the images or links from the original page. A square box comes up, which you can interact with to login to the site, put you can still see everything from the original page.

I've been searching and searching and I can't find what I'm looking for. I just need some ideas to get me pointed in the right direction and I can go from there.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Consider renaming the question. Implying server-side issues, it's a little misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) could help you. Checkout the [modal example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into [Colorbox](http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) - it's a jQuery plugin, very easy to use, and does exactly what you want.

The effect of graying out the page and showing a popup dialogue box is called a "modal" dialogue box.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the functionality you are referring to is called a `lightbox`.

There are dozens of [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) lightbox plugins around, a quick Google search suffices; [FancyBox](http://fancybox.net/), for example, is a pretty nice one.